# Cypress (12.16) how do look for a particular ID and if it isn't found then move on to an alternate?

Tags: javascript, attributes, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

Pretty new to cypress (12.16) here and have a question:

I have a form that gets used in multiple areas of the app, I’m trying to turn filling it out into a command to centralize it in case we need to change variables, the issue is that I need to select an element which has an ID that can be either ‘UI-1’ or ‘UI-2’, and my JavaScript isn’t great - I’m wondering if there’s a way to build a selector that essentially looks for 'UI-1' and if it doesn’t find it then look for 'UI-2' and continue.

Comment: I originally thought of using something like Cy.get(‘[id=“UI-“]’) but the issue with that is there are actually two different elements that have two UI- ids, so I would have to specify UI-1 or UI-2 for the first set and UI-3 or UI-4 for the second

Answer (score 2):

You can take the approach of partial attributes, since `id="UI-1"` is an attribute you are not limited to using `#UI-1`.

You can also use `[id="UI-1"]` and there are variations one of which is startsWith `[id^="UI-"]` which will find any `id` starting with `UI-`.

See this page for a complete list [jQuery Attribute selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

If you pick up multiple elements, use `.each()` to process them

```js
cy.get('[id^="UI-"]')
  .each($el => {
    if ($el.attr('id') === 'UI-1' || $el.attr('id') === 'UI-2') {   
      cy.wrap($el).type('abc')
    } 
    if ($el.attr('id') === 'UI-3' || $el.attr('id') === 'UI-4') {   
      cy.wrap($el).type('def')
    } 
  })
```

or use a mapping

```js
cy.get('[id^="UI-"]')
  .each($el => {
    const textForId = {
      'UI-1': 'abc',
      'UI-2': 'abc',
      'UI-3': 'def',
      'UI-4': 'def',
    }
    const id = $el.attr('id')
    cy.wrap($el).type(textForId[id])
  })
```

---

As for a custom command, it's pretty simple

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getElementsWithIdStarting_UI', () => {
  cy.get('[id^="UI-"]')
})
```

You can put it into the support folder to centralize the code (although I wouldn't bother with that, since global searching is pretty easy when you need to update the selector).